# Is it possible to use spring boot properties in a sql file?

Tags: sql, spring-boot

i would like to use spring boot properties in a sql file. Do you know how it can be done? thanks!

Comment: welcome to SO. Can you please provide more details ? what do u mean by using spring boot properties  in SQLfile?

Comment: Hello Niraj. I have a spring application with sql files in resources folder. I want to know if it is possible to use spring properties declared in application.yml in thoses sql files.